# How to capture the fname of file in the IICS Infromatica mass ingestion?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, iics

Hi i am loading mutliple files to the snowflake table using informatica iics.I want to capture the file name along with the data.In file list method it is possible but mass ingestion its not.Can you suggest some methods to do this task.file list is not being supported by the client network.

Comment: I guess with MI the only option will be to go through the task log file.